# Change Post Publish Date to Post Modified Date in All Places

Tags: actions, date

I need to change post publish date to modify date every where in my theme.

I know that I can use `the_modified_date()` function to display post modify date.

But changing in every place takes too much time.

Is there any way to change it using action hook or filter? (All theme in just one place)

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if this would work for you:

```
is_admin() || add_filter( 'get_the_date', function( $the_time, $d, $post  ) 
{
     return get_the_modified_date( $d, $post );
}, 10, 3 );
```

where we override the output of `get_the_date()` with `get_the_modified_date()`, for the front-end.